# How to know the current configuration options of the running Emacs?

Tags: build

How can I know the current configuration options, like
`with-cocoa`, `with-librsvg`, `with-modules`(i.e. the options using when Emacs was built), of the running Emacs, programmatically?

Comment: `M-x emacs-version` tells you some info. `M-x report-emacs-bug` tells you much more (you need not finish submitting a bug report).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the variable `system-configuration-options` with <kbd>C-h v system-configuration-options</kbd>

> system-configuration-options is a variable defined in `C source code'.
>   Its value is ""
>
> Documentation: String containing the configuration options Emacs was
>   built with.

In my case, the value is: `"--host=x86_64-debian-linux-gnu --with-modules"`